# Tracking html 5 audio buffering on Android

Tags: android, buffer, html5-audio

I am developing a web app that needs to run on desktop browsers, iPad and Android tablet(Samsung galaxy).

Before showing pages I just want preload page specific assets first.

I can buffer audio and preload images on all platforms except Android Tablet.

I am using "audio[0].buffered.end(1)" to track audio buffering but only on android its not working.

Please let me know if it is possible to track audio buffering on Android tablet(Galaxy).

Comment: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/ and http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/buffering/

Comment: I test longtail video on my android device. its not showing buffering progress. :(